# Python : parasitic number

Tags: python

In general, a positive natural number that can be multiplied by n 
by moving the rightmost digit to the front of the number is called an n 
-parasitic number. Here n is itself a single-digit positive natural number. For example: 4×128205=512820 
         4×128205=512820
so 128205 is a 4-parasitic number. Natural numbers with leading zeros are not allowed. So even though 
4×025641=102564 
4×025641=102564
the number 025641 is not 4-parasitic.

Assignment: write a function parasitic that takes a natural number. In case the given natural number is n-parasitic, the function must return the value n. Otherwise, the function must return the value 0.

My code (last definition parastic(number)) is not working for some cases for example: parasitic(142857)
n = 5 while with my code I return 0.

```
def rotateLeft(number):
    """
    >>> rotateLeft(717948)
    179487
    >>> rotateLeft(142857)
    428571
    >>> rotateLeft(105263157894736842)
    52631578947368421
    """

    k = str(number)
    letter = k[:1]
    numb = k[1:]
    resultaat = str(numb) + str(letter)
    return int(resultaat)



def rotateRight(number):
    """
    >>> rotateRight(179487)
    717948
    >>> rotateRight(428571)
    142857  
    >>> rotateRight(52631578947368421)
    15263157894736842
    """

    k = str(number)
    letter = k[-1]
    numb = k[:-1]
    resultaat = str(letter) + str(numb)  
    return int(resultaat)

def parasitic(number):
    """
    >>> parasitic(179487)
    4
    >>> parasitic(142857)
    5
    >>> parasitic(105263157894736842)
    2
    >>> parasitic(1234)
    0
    """


    count = 0
    getal = count * number

    while getal != rotateLeft(number):
        count += 1
        getal = count * number
        if getal == rotateLeft(number):
            break
            return (count)
        else:
            return 0
```

Comment: `if getal == rotateLeft(number):
            break
            return (count)` : that never returns `count`

Comment: your last while loop is dubious: it returns (or breaks) at the first iteration

Comment: I get 0 with all your values. Did you post the correct code?

Comment: Regards @Lien , But I don't think that 179487 is 4-parasitic.

Comment: I think your `else : return 0` stops the loop after the first count. So it wont reach the desired output. This is because at the first count, 0 x number is clearly not parasitic, so it would return 0 immediately.

Comment: You don't need to use `str(numb)` and `str(letter)`. They're already strings.

Comment: And calling the variable `letter` is very confusing -- it contains digits, not letters.

Answer (score 2):

While using a `while` loop may improve your grasp of python, this can be solved rather simply using the `%` operator.

```
def rotateRight(number):
    """
    >>> rotateRight(179487)
    717948
    >>> rotateRight(428571)
    142857  
    >>> rotateRight(52631578947368421)
    15263157894736842
    """
    k = str(number)
    return int(k[-1] + k[:-1])

def parasitic(number):
    rotated = rotateRight(number)
    if not rotated % number:
        return rotated // number
    else:
        return 0
```

This tests to see if `number` is divisible by the number obtained by a right-rotation, and, if so, returns the divisor (the `//` operator rounds the result to the nearest integer, but we already know the result must be an integer)

Comment: Exactly. There's absolutely no need for any loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a `function` that seems to do the job for your examples!

It uses `concatenation` of `string` `slices` and compares this against the  `num`. I think a trick is that `n` can only ever be between `2` and `11` for this to work as otherwise the shift by `1` at the end would never make the original `number`.

Here's the code:

```
def parasitic(num):
    for n in range(2, 11):
        res = n * num
        if str(num)[-1] + str(num)[:-1] == str(res):
            return n
    return False
```

Testing:

```
>>> parasitic(128205)
4
>>> parasitic(142857)
5
>>> parasitic(105263157894736842)
2
>>> parasitic(35)
False
```

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: @Lien Click the arrow above the `0` next to the answer and the grey (green after clicked) arrow in the same location **:)**

Comment: It's too early to accept any answer. For this problem, no loop is needed at all. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47021741/6419007).

Comment: Also, you shouldn't calculate `str(num)[-1] + str(num)[:-1]` over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue (having removed break, which is the first issue as it ends before it can return anything):

```
if getal==rotateLeft(number):
    return count
else:
    return 0
```

I think you intended a while-else loop, but you ended up with "if the first result doesn't work, return 0". You need to change indentation so the else lines up the the while (so if no result is found, return 0), not the if. You will also have to add a limit of what to check, or if there is no result it will go on forever.

```
while getal != rotateLeft(number):
   count += 1
   getal = count * number
   if getal == rotateLeft(number):
        return (count)
else:
   return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number is parasitic, the `while` loop will eventually stop even without you put `break` in it. I would suggest not to use `while` loop with this current conditon, since this will be infinity-loop if the number is not parasitic.

But I may show that your code would work if you remove the `return` in `else` condition. And also you may want to add both condition of `rotateLeft` and `rotateRight` :

```
def parasitic(number):
    count = 0;
    getal = count * number;

    while getal != rotateLeft(number) and getal != rotateRight(number) :
        count += 1
        getal = int(count * number)
        if getal == rotateLeft(number) or getal == rotateRight(number)  :
            print(count); print(getal);
            return (count)
        else:
            pass
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
    if getal == rotateLeft(number):
        break
        return (count)
```

Since `break` leaves the loop, you cannot ever reach the `return` statement; your code would simply fall off the end of the function, and return `None`.

Also, your double-check of `getal == rotateLeft(number)` signals poor loop design; you should be able to test this *once* at the top of the loop, without making a second check within.

**REPAIR**

You have to handle two cases:

1. If you find a multiplier that matches the rotation, return that multiplier.
2. If *all* valid multipliers fail, *then* you return 0.

So (a) how many multipliers do you try before you give up?
(b) where do you put the two different `return` statements to handle those cases?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre correct; this is not a one-shot logic error.